# bash for script and input parameter

Tags: bash

Can anyone help me to modify my script. Because it does not work. Here are three scripts. 
1) pb.sh, use delphicpp_release software to read the 1brs.ab.sh and will give the output as 1brs.ab.out

2) 1brs.ab.sh, use for input parameter where a.sh(another script for protein structure), chramm.siz, charmm.crg are file for atom size and charge etc. rest of the parameters for run the delphicpp_release software.

3) a.sh, use for read several protein structures, which will be in the same directory.

my script_1 = pb.sh:

```
  ./delphicpp_release 1brs.ab.sh >1brs.ab.out   
   echo PB-Energy-AB = $(grep -oP '(?<=Energy> Corrected:).*' 1brs.ab.out) >>PB-energy.dat

   cat PB-energy.dat
```

script_2 = 1brs.ab.sh:

```
in(pdb,file="a.sh")
in(siz,file="charmm.siz")
in(crg,file="charmm.crg")
perfil=70 
scale=2.0
indi=4
exdi=80.0
prbrad=1.4
salt=0.15
bndcon=2
maxc=0.0001
linit=800
energy(s)
```

script_3 = a.sh:

```
for i in $(seq 90000 20 90040); do
   $i.pdb 
done
```

Comment: I don't think people would be able to deduce from your question 1. What you are trying to achieve 2)What you've done so far. Also, it doesn't look like a bash script to me. for instance what is `in(crg,file="charmm.crg")`

Comment: 1) I am trying to use the software which measure the binding energy of my system which mention in parameter file (a.para, b.para.) 90000.ab.pdb, 90020.ab.pdb.... 2) charmm.siz, charmm.crg are input parameter files. 3) In my script everything will be same, only 90000.ab.pdb, 90020.ab.pdb, 90040.ab.pdb .... 100000.ab.pdb will be input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we don't know what `software` is, something like

```
for ((i=90000;i<=100000;i+=20)); do
    ./software << "    DATA_END" > 1brs.$i.a.out 
    scale=2.0 
    in(pdb,file="../$i.ab.pdb")
    in(siz,file="charmm.siz")
    in(crg,file="charmm.crg")
    indi=z
    exdi=x
    prbrad=y
    DATA_END
    echo Energy-A = $(grep -oP '(?<=Energy>:).*' 1brs.$i.a.out) >>PB-energy.dat
done
```

A more POSIX shell compliant version

```
i=90000
while ((i<=100000)); do
    ...
    ((i+=20));
done
```

EDIT: Without heredoc

```
{
    echo 'scale=2.0'
    echo 'in(pdb,file="../'"$i"'.ab.pdb")'
    echo 'in(siz,file="charmm.siz")'
    echo 'in(crg,file="charmm.crg")'
    echo 'indi=z'
    echo 'exdi=x'
    echo 'prbrad=y'
} > $i.ab.sh
./software <$i.ab.sh >$i.ab.out
```

but as question was changed I'm not sure to understand it.

Comment: Software is binary software which will run the input parameter and give the energy

Comment: dear sir, it gives me Syntax error: Bad for loop variable

Comment: Dear sir, what does this command do << "    DATA_END" >? because here should be "a.para" and how software read that parameter files

Comment: `<<` followed by marker allows to pass a heredoc as input for command so that $i can be changed in input otherwise a temporary file can be created, updating answer